# PHP checking empty fields Login

Tags: php

I have a select action and I want to check if the fields `username` and `password` are both empty. My issue is that if one of them is empty echo msg pops but, but if both are empty it goes straight to the next page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    include_once("connexion.php");
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password  FROM users where username = '$username' and password ='$password'";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon,$sql);

    if ($query) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $userId = $row[0];
        $dbUsername = $row[1];
        $dbPassword = $row[2];
    }

    if ($username == $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
        header('location:../index-2.php');
    } else {
        echo "wrong username or password";
    }
}
?>
```

Edit : I used Dharmesh Goswami solution :

```
if ($username == $dbUsername && !empty($username) && $password == $dbPassword && empty($password) )
```

It works like a charm ! Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `empty()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: That's because the DB result will be empty too, Check that the Username and Password isn't empty before comparing the values.

Comment: Check [PHP: SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) as well - strip_tags() ain't nearly enough ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check in if condition that both are not empty.

```
if ($username == $dbUsername && !empty($username) && $password == $dbPassword && !empty($password) )
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
    header('location:../index-2.php');
}else
{
    echo "wrong username or password";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) condition right after form posted.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
  $username = trim($username);
  $password = trim($password);
  if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    // Print your error.
  }
}
```

`||` will check if any one or both the fields are empty.

Comment: You might want to consider trimming?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to check if input string is empty or not. To check if one of the fields is empty, you could use the XOR(^) operator. Failing which, the control should pass to AND(&&) operator which checks if both the fields are empty. If that fails too, you could say that none of the fields is empty. Hope this helps.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
   if(empty($_POST['username'] ^ empty($_POST['password']){
   // code here to perform task if one field is left empty

   } else if(empty($POST['username'] && empty($_POST['password']){
   // code here to perform task if both fields are empty  

   } else {
   // code here to perform task when none of the fields is empty

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You do like that

extract($_POST);
if($_POST['submit']) :
if($Username == "" && $Password == ""):
$_SESSION['error'] = "Can't Be Blanked User Name Or Password";
endif;
endif;
```

Comment: This is somewhat over the top. Why would you extract `$_POST`?

Comment: Also the PHP documentation clearly states not to use it on user input: *Warning Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input* (http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: usually I do use extract($_POST); instead of $_POST['Username'];  etc and because $_POST is in the array form so I have to define like that, simply extract and get output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['username']);
```

same for password

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, username, password  FROM use...';
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$count = $conn->affected_rows;
if ($count == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
    header('location:../index-2.php');
}else echo "wrong username or password";
```

also, wouldn't save username in sessions. Look up more on securing session.